# PHPStorm does not read the entire path to the php interpretator

Tags: php, windows, phpstorm

Hi I just installed PHPStorm 5 for the first time to give it a try and I seem to be having a problem in running PHP applications.I have installed xampp and the path to the PHP interpretator has been set to:

```
D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe
```

When I try to run I php file I get this error:

```
"D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe" D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe "D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\PHPStorm\Project\index.php"

Could not open input file: D:\Program

Process finished with exit code 1
```

For some reason it seems that PHPStorm does not read the rest of the path and it stops at  D:\Program.

How can I correct this problem besides changing the name of the folder because that would require me to reinstall almost everything on my computer again?

**EDIT RUN CONFIGURATION**

[image]

Comment: You try to make PHP execute the PHP path. Looks like you totally screwed the setting. Press F1 and read what to enter where. - Just that you don't look too much in the wrong directions: You don't need to rename any folder. PHPStorm work with multiple PHP binaries with or without spaces inside their full path.

Comment: THen how come it says could not open Could not open input file: D:\Program and it stopes there?

Comment: *That* error is because of missing quotes ***however*** you did enter something into a totally wrong field. So adding quotes won't make it execute your PHP script in the editor. You just messed something more basic up. Post a screenshot of your run configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look the full command-line:

```
"D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe" D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe ⤦ 
  "D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\PHPStorm\Project\index.php"
```

You are using the command:

```
 "D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe"
```

With the following three parameters:

1. D:\Program
2. Files\xampp\php\php.exe
3. "D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\PHPStorm\Project\index.php"

You `php.exe` then tries to open the "file"

```
D:\Program
```

and naturally fails. Instead your command should be:

```
"D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe" c:\path\to\your\script.php
```

Obviously you did enter the text *D:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe* into too many textboxes as it belongs to. If you're new to PHPStorm I suggest you read the online manual:

- [Interpreters - PhpStorm 5.0 Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/interpreters.html)
- [Run/Debug Configuration: PHP Script - PhpStorm 5.0 Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-php-script.html)

It's also available by pressing F1 when you're in a dialog.

---

**Edit:** Clear the field named *Interpreator Options*